# How to do "else" in bash case command?

Tags: bash

```
filter="yes"
phonenumbers=(123 456 789 987 654 321)
echo "checking inbox now..."
myphonenumber=(7892)

if [[ "$filter" == "yes" ]]; then
    case "${phonenumbers[@]}" in
        *"$myphonenumber"*) echo "filter is on, phone number matches" 
        ;;
        !="$myphonenumber") echo "filter is on but the phone number doesn't match" 
        ;;
    esac
fi

if [[ "$filter" == "no" ]]; then
    echo "filter off"
fi
```

I try running that script but it doesn't work, how should I display the `filter is on but the phone number doesn't match` part? I'm still learning, I know I can do it with `if else` statement but I wonder if I can do it with `case` too.

Comment: I've edited your script to improve your indentation. Hopefully that will help you see a bit better what the case labels are actually doing (also to make it even remotely readable).

Comment: This is mentioned (though not prominently) in the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html): "It’s a common idiom to use ‘*’ as the final pattern to define the default case, since that pattern will always match."

Answer (score 10):

Solved with this `*)` so the whole code is:

```
filter="yes"
phonenumbers=(123 456 789 987 654 321)
echo "checking inbox now..."
myphonenumber=(7892)

if [[ "$filter" == "yes" ]]; then
  case "${phonenumbers[@]}" in
    *"$myphonenumber"*) echo "filter is on, phone number matches" ;;
    *)                  echo "filter is on but the phone number doesn't match" ;;
  esac
fi

if [[ "$filter" == "no" ]]; then
  echo "filter off"
fi
```

Comment: Yes, thank you I just edited my code to look a bit more understandable now.

Comment: I hope you'll forgive me for making a few more edits along those lines. By the way, is this homework? I've seen someone else ask an almost-identical question very recently.

Comment: On a different point, your comparison here is a bit buggy -- if `myphonenumber="123 456"`, then you get a match claimed, even though there's no single phone number containing that string. (Also, `${phonenumbers[*]}` is the Right Thing if you want to expand an array into a single string to compare against; using the list expansion `"${phonenumbers[@]}"` in a context where a single scalar variable is expected inside `[[ ]]` is undefined behavior).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy No, I'm not a college student, I teach myself this programming language. If you don't mind please show me the right code, thank you.

Comment: Ahh -- that other question was also yours; now this makes sense. The other question I linked yours too when closing it as duplicate has an answer showing the best-practices approach for set membership; see also BashFAQ #6 on associative arrays: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for something similar to a `default` statement of a `switch` in a C-like language, the following should handle this. Observe the `*)` clause.

For a bit of reference, http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html

```
filter="yes"
phonenumbers=(123 456 789 987 654 321)
echo "checking inbox now..."
myphonenumber=(7892)

if [[ "$filter" == "yes" ]]; then
    case "${phonenumbers[@]}" in  
        *"$myphonenumber"*) echo "filter is on, phone number matches" 
        ;; 
        *) echo "filter is on but the phone number doesn't match" 
        ;; 
    esac
fi

if [[ "$filter" == "no" ]]; then
    echo "filter off"
fi
```